# Gerenciamento de Janelas Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

eu estou fazendo um codigo na qual a janela principal tem 4 botões (Criar, gerenciar, Deletar e Sobre) e eu queria que na hora que eu clicar no botao criar isse para a aba de criação sem ter que abrir uma outra janela(Ficar duas janelas) ou fechar a principal e abrir e outra(ou seja fecha e abre).
Tipo o Ccleaner, voce clica e configuração, ai na mesma janela ele sair da parte de analisar e abre a configuração.

Código :

```
from tkinter import *
from sqlite3 import *

class criar(object):
    def __init__(self, principal):
#frames e empacotamento de frames
        self.frame1 = Frame(principal)
        self.frame1.place()
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2 = Frame(principal)
        self.frame2.place()
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.subFrameOptions = Frame(self.frame2)
        self.subFrameOptions.place()
        self.subFrameOptions.pack()
#texto exibido na tela
        L1 = Label(self.frame1, text = "Nome do Seu Banco de Dado")
        L1.place(x = 10,y = 10)
        L1.pack()
        E1 = Entry(self.frame1, bd = 5, )
        E1.place(x = 60,y = 10)
        E1.pack()
#checkButtons
        self.nome = Checkbutton(self.subFrameOptions, bd = 5, text = 'Nome', variable = Vnome)
        self.nome.pack(side = LEFT)
        Vnome.get()
        self.cor = Checkbutton(self.subFrameOptions, bd = 5, text = 'Cor', variable = Vcor)
        self.cor.pack(side = LEFT)
        Vcor.get()
        self.cpf = Checkbutton(self.subFrameOptions, bd = 5, text = 'CPF', variable = Vcpf)
        self.cpf.pack(side = LEFT)
        Vcpf.get()
        self.email = Checkbutton(self.subFrameOptions, bd = 5, text = 'Email', variable = Vemail)
        self.email.pack(side = LEFT)
        Vemail.get()


principal = Tk()
#variaveis dos metodos dos checkButtons
Vnome = IntVar()
Vcor = IntVar()
Vcpf = IntVar()
Vemail = IntVar()
#cria a instancia
criar(principal)
principal.geometry('400x300')
principal.title("Gerenciador de Cadastro")
principal.mainloop()
```

Ai ja da pra ver que eu quero criar um programa gerenciador de banco de dados na qual o usuario digita o nome do banco e marcas as opções digitadas. soque eu quero fazer uma coisa tipo (Pseudo codigo): clico no botao cria coloco o nome marco as opçoes de dados no banco e em seguida envio o codigo e ja entro no gerenciamento para olhar o banco de dados criado, porem não quero que o programa fique abrindo e fechando janela, quero que na mesma janela ele mude de aba.

Comment: Visto que se registrou hoje no site, recomendo que faça primeiramente o [tour] para entender pelo menos o básico do funcionamento do sistema. Após, você pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código que você já possui para que possamos entender melhor o que você já fez e necessita fazer. Para a formatação do código, basta copiá-lo no editor da pergunta, selecionálo e pressionar `Ctrl+K`.

Comment: pronto arrumei arrumei a pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você pode utilizar `.pack_forget()` para eliminar os widget que você deu `.pack()` e aí dar `.pack()` em outro widget que você gostaria que ficasse naquele frame.

**Exemplo:**

Espero ter ficado mais claro com esse exemplo.

```
from tkinter import *

class exemplo:
    def __init__(self, tk):
        self.frame1 = Frame(tk)
        self.frame2 = Frame(tk)
        self.frame3 = Frame(tk)

        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.frame3.pack()

        self.Botao1 = Button(self.frame1, text='Clique nesse botão para alterar.', command=self.alterar, bg='darkred')
        self.entrada1 = Label(self.frame2, text='Usuário:', width=8, height=2)
        self.entrada2 = Entry(self.frame2)

        self.Botao1.pack()
        self.entrada1.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.entrada2.pack(side=LEFT)

    def alterar(self):
        self.Botao1.pack_forget() #Retiro todos esses
        self.entrada1.pack_forget() #Retiro todos esses
        self.entrada2.pack_forget() #Retiro todos esses

        # E no frame aonde os três acima estavam, eu coloquei esses:
        self.Botao2 = Button(self.frame3, text='Clique nesse botão para voltar.', command=self.reverter, bg='darkgray')
        self.entrada3 = Label(self.frame2, text='Digite algo acima', height=2)
        self.entrada4 = Entry(self.frame1)

        self.Botao2.pack()
        self.entrada3.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.entrada4.pack(side=LEFT)

    def reverter(self):
        self.Botao1.pack() # Para reverter eu simplesmente dei .pack() nesses
        self.entrada1.pack() # Para reverter eu simplesmente dei .pack() nesses
        self.entrada2.pack() # Para reverter eu simplesmente dei .pack() nesses

        self.Botao2.pack_forget() # e "eliminei esses". Se isso não for feito, ambos ocupam o mesmo Frame.
        self.entrada3.pack_forget() # e "eliminei esses". Se isso não for feito, ambos ocupam o mesmo Frame.
        self.entrada4.pack_forget() # e "eliminei esses". Se isso não for feito, ambos ocupam o mesmo Frame.
ex = Tk()
exemplo(ex)
ex.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ajudou muito vlw

Comment: tu poderia meu ajudar com outro problema porfavor ?

Comment: Se eu puder eu ajudo sim, eu não entendo muito de Tkinter.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204894/bot%C3%A3o-enviar-ou-atualizar-no-tkinter-python-e-redimensionamento-de-widgets