# Botão enviar ou atualizar no Tkinter (Python) e Redimensionamento de Widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

Inicie um codigo na qual tem 4 ChecksButtons e eu queria fazer o seguinte:
(pseudo-Código) usuário digita o nome do banco de dados, e seleciona oque ele quer => nome, email, cpf, cor após isso o programa pega e verifica qual está selecionado, apos a verificação se nome estive marcado pega e criar um dado do nome na tabela e assim por diante. minha dificuldade e na verificação se o CheckButton tá ou não marcado e se tiver pega e faz algo.

Outro problema meu é em redimensionamento de widgets tipo que colocar o entry em tal lugar porem ele so fica no topo.

```
from tkinter import *

class criar(object):
    def __init__(self, principal):
#frames e empacotamento de frames
        self.font = ('Arial', '18', 'bold')
        self.frame1 = Frame(principal)
        self.frame1.place()
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2 = Frame(principal)
        self.frame2.place()
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.subFrameOptions = Frame(self.frame2)
        self.subFrameOptions.place()
        self.subFrameOptions.pack()
#texto exibido na tela
        for i in range(15):
           L3 = Label(self.frame1, text = '\t\t\t\t\t\t', bg = '#B5B5B5')
           L3.pack()
        L1 = Label(self.frame1, font = self.font, text = "  Nome do Seu Banco de Dado  ", bg = '#696969')
        L1.place(x = 10,y = 10)
        L1.pack()
        E1 = Entry(self.frame1, bd = 5, highlightcolor = '#1E90FF')
        E1.place(x = 40,y = 10)
        E1.pack()
        L2 = Label(self.frame1, text = '\t\t\t\t\t\t', bg = '#B5B5B5')
        L2.pack()
#checkButtons
        self.nome = Checkbutton(self.subFrameOptions, bd = 5, text = 'Nome', variable = Vnome)
        self.nome.pack(side = LEFT)
        Vnome.get()
        self.cor = Checkbutton(self.subFrameOptions, bd = 5, text = 'Cor', variable = Vcor)
        self.cor.pack(side = LEFT)
        Vcor.get()
        self.cpf = Checkbutton(self.subFrameOptions, bd = 5, text = 'CPF', variable = Vcpf)
        self.cpf.pack(side = LEFT)
        Vcpf.get()
        self.email = Checkbutton(self.subFrameOptions, bd = 5, text = 'Email', variable = Vemail)
        self.email.pack(side = LEFT)
        Vemail.get()


principal = Tk()
#variaveis dos metodos dos checkButtons
Vnome = IntVar()
Vcor = IntVar()
Vcpf = IntVar()
Vemail = IntVar()
#cria a instancia
criar(principal)
principal['bg'] = '#B5B5B5'
principal.geometry('400x300')
principal.title("Gerenciador de Cadastro")
principal.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu tinha postado uma solução que eu tinha encontrado para saber quando a caixa fosse marcada, mas agora editei por que encontrei a forma correta, que é até bem parecida com a que eu tinha colocado aqui.

A explicação de como fazer para reconhecer está dentro do algoritmo.

```
from tkinter import *

class exemplo:
    def __init__(self, tk):
        self.frame1 = Frame(tk)
        self.frame2 = Frame(tk)

        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2.pack()

        self.aviso = Label(self.frame2, text='Desmarcado')
        self.aviso.pack()

        self.es_C1 = IntVar() #self.es_NomeVariável = IntVar(), explico o que é IntVar() lá embaixo.
        self.C1 = Checkbutton(tk, text = "Music",  height=2,
                 width = 15, command=self.marcada, variable=self.es_C1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
"""
* "onvalue" é o valor que será dado quando a caixa estiver marcada, aqui eu defini 1, mas não é necessário coloca-la dentro do CheckButton, o valor é sempre 1
* "offvalue" é o inverso, eu defini 0, também não precisa colocar, valor padrão é sempre 0.
* Só coloca "onvalue" e "offvalue" se você você quiser colocar um valor diferente como "marcado" ou "desmarcado", eles sempre estarão presentes na função com valor 1 e 0 respectivamente.
* "variable" é onde é "depositado" o estado atual do CheckButton, definido por "onvalue" e "offvalue".
"""
        self.C1.pack()
    def marcada(self):
        if self.es_C1.get() == 1: #utilizamos .get() para pegarmos o valor da variável e comparamos com 1, se estiver marcado, exibe o aviso de marcado.
            self.aviso['text'] = 'Marcado'
        else:
            self.aviso['text'] = 'Desmarcado'
ex = Tk()
exemplo(ex)
ex.mainloop()
```

Checando a mensagem acima da caixa, você vê que ao marca-la aparece a mensagem `Marcado`, e quando desmarca `Desmarcado`. Agora é só você conseguir encaixar no teu código.

**Entry:**

Para o `Entry()` ficar à esquerda é só colocar o que você colocou nos outros, `side=LEFT`, espero ter ajudado.